Unexplained delay in Istio / Envoy proxy connection. How to get more details?
I'm seeing a rather large delay from the outbound of one service's envoy proxy to the inbound of another service's envoy proxy.
Here is a trace of the interaction with comments

Particularly, from Service 2's Outbound Envoy to Service 3's inbound envoy, there's a 750ms delay.
I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is happening during this 750ms delay. Is it DNS? Is it contention? I'm not sure.
What Istio or Envoy metrics or other means (logs at a certain level?) could help with diagnosing and give more insight to what is happening during this 750 ms delay?
